# Accessing elements in JSON array

Tags: java, arrays, json, google-api

I haven't worked much with JSON and I'm using Google Maps Distance Matrix API to get generate some data I'd like to use.

I'd like to pull the number **14147** from *duration*.

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "226 mi",
                  "value" : 364089
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 56 mins",
                  "value" : 14147
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I've tried a few different things, here's what I tried last (data is just the array above):

```
String data = getOutputAsText(geoService);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
String duration = json.getJSONArray("rows").getString("duration");
```

Here's the console output:

```
 org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["duration"] not found
```

I made sure to look around before posting but I haven't found anything that has been able to help me with this particular problem.

I want to pass the value from duration to my own web service, which I can do, I just don't know how to extract the value.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Create classes representing the data stored in the JSON then just use Jackson to convert from JSON to those classes.

Comment: Which library do you use to parse your Json?

Comment: @DwB I wouldnt create the Java model for this small json snippet. Id rather parse it "dynamically"

Comment: @ArthurEirich Thank you :) I found a solution from the links and example you provided.

Comment: @Andremoniy I edited the OP and didn't proof read that last part, my bad.  So embarrassing! haha

Comment: @Ceginner You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json#18998203) answer. Using [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) you can do smth. like that:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("Content of your string here");
JSONArray rows = obj.getJSONArray("rows");
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++) {
 JSONArray elements = rows.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("elements");
  for(int j = 0; j < elements.length(); j++) {
   JSONObject element = elements.getJSONObject(j);
   JSONObject duration = element.getJSONObject("duration");
   int value = duration.getInt("value");
  }
 }
```

The code above has produced following output using your json String: `14147`

P.S. You can make use of a library you wish. This one used here was purposed for the demonstrating.